# PHP get content of file in UCS-2 LE BOM encoding and replace strings in it

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to get the content of a .csv file and replace some strings in it. To do that, I use the following simple code:

```
    $pattern = "test";
    $replacement = "Replacement";
    $string = file_get_contents( "myDoc.csv" );
    $string =  str_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );
```

However, what $string holds:

```
echo $string; // Outputs: This is my test 
var_dump($string); // Outputs: string(32) "��This is my test"
```

I found out the file is in UCS-2 LE BOM encoding. If I convert the file to another encoding, I will probably lose some symbols/characters.

It is essential that the file has the same format and the content is not modified in any way (except for the targeted strings).

How should I make the replacement of the strings so that I don't lose information?

Answer (score 2):

### Stripping off the BOM

The [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is a sequence of bytes at the beginning of the file. For example, for UTF-8 it is a sequence of three bytes: `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. For UTF-16 Little-endian (LE), BOM is represented as two bytes: `0xFF 0xFE`. So you can remove them simply with a regular expression. E.g.:

```
function stripUtf8Bom($string) {
    return preg_replace('/^\xef\xbb\xbf/', '', $string);
}

function stripUtf16Le($string) {
    return preg_replace('/^\xff\xfe/', '', $string);
}

function stripUtf16Be($string) {
    return preg_replace('/^\xfe\xff/', '', $string);
}
```

### Substring Replacement

The standard string functions such as `str_replace` do not support multi-byte characters. Use [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php) functions instead:

> `mbstring` is designed to handle Unicode-based encodings such as UTF-8
>   and UCS-2 and many single-byte encodings for convenience...

You may find [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) function particularly useful.

Comment: Even if I do that, I cannot replace any strings in the text

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I did not know that. However, it still does not replace the words. What I did is to encode the $pattern and $replacement to match the encoding of the document so I think it works now...

Comment: @Dimentica, I can't say why your code doesn't replace the words, because I don't see your code with `mbstring` functions.